# Multiple images Upload With php not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images (actually, 8 images) but they're not mandatory.

In my php, I use a foreach to upload the files and send the links by email but they're not uploading.

What I could be wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $local = $_POST['local'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $whatsapp = $_POST['whatsapp'];
    $idade = $_POST['idade'];
    $cache = $_POST['cache'];
    $atendimento = $_POST['atendimento'];
    $atendo = $_POST['atendo'];
    $pagamento = $_POST['pagamento'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];

    $para = "email@gmail.com";

    $texto = "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $texto .= "<b>Nome: </b>". $nome ."<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>E-mail: </b>". $email ."<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Local: </b>". $local ."<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Telefone: </b>". $telefone ."<br />";
    if($whatsapp)   {
        $texto .= "<b>Whatsapp:</b> Sim<br />";
    };
    $texto .= "<b>Idade: </b>". $idade ."<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Cachê: </b>". $cache ."<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Atendimento: </b>";
    foreach($atendimento as $Atendimento)   {
        $texto .= $Atendimento .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Atendo: </b>";
    foreach($atendo as $Atendo) {
        $texto .= $Atendo .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Formas de Pagamento: </b>";
    foreach($pagamento as $Pagamento)   {
        $texto .= $Pagamento .", ";
    };
    $texto .= "<br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Mensagem: </b>". $mensagem ."<br />";
    $txt1 = "email@gmail.com";
    $contador = 0;
    $diretorio = "envios/";
    foreach($imagem as $img)    {
        if(!empty($img["name"]))    {
            $arquivo = $diretorio . basename($img["name"]);
            $tipoimagem = pathinfo($arquivo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($tipoimagem != "jpg" && $tipoimagem != "png" && $tipoimagem != "jpeg" && $tipoimagem != "gif" ) {
                echo "apenas arquivos JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF são permitidos.";
            } else  {
                if(move_uploaded_file($img["tmp_name"], $arquivo))   {
                $contador = $contador + 1;
                $texto .= "<b>Foto ". $contador .":</b> ". $arquivo ."<br />";
                } else  {
                    echo "<script>alert('Ops!')</script>";
                }
            };
        };
    };

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"$nome\" <$email>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Bcc: {$txt1}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    mail($para,"Contato Anuncio",$texto,$headers);
    echo "<script>alert('Mensagem Enviada!')</script>";

?>
```

Comment: "not working" isn't very specific. have you checked the error logs? any more information?

Comment: The file isn't uploaded and I'm not founding my error log file to check it

Comment: Okay, well report back when you do [find it](https://www.google.com/#q=php+where+is+my+error+log). That should help narrow it down.

Comment: Found the log, read it, but nothing related to my php file or the html where the form is.

Comment: Lots of possible issues. Maybe the files exceed the maximum upload size in php.ini, maybe you don't have write permissions on the folder you're copying to. You need to narrow it down. For example, in your `foreach`, put `echo 'here'; exit;` on each line until you find out where it's failing. Also see [common pitfalls](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php).

Comment: Is something in my foreach function, but I Revised everything and found nothing yet.. My php.ini is okay.